# The truth value of an array with more than one element

Tags: python

I input the date arrays in another file and called this function below but it returned an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jiangyunke/Desktop/My Python/Interest Rate Curve/venv/swap.py", line 21, in <module>
    "30/360": Z.X_30360()}
  File "/Users/jiangyunke/Desktop/My Python/Interest Rate Curve/venv/DayCountConvention.py", line 44, in X_30360
    + 30 * (d2_month - d1_month - 1)) / 360
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I deal with this problem?
the code is below:

```
def X_30360(self):
    d1_month = list(self.d1.month)
    d2_month = list(self.d2.month)
    d1_year = list(self.d1.year)
    d2_year = list(self.d2.year)
    if d2_month == d1_month:
        d_30360 = (360 * (d2_year - d1_year) + self.d2.day - self.d1.day) / 360
    else:
        d_30360 = (max(0, 30 - self.d1.day) + min(30, self.d2.day) + 360 * (d2_year - d1_year)
        + 30 * (d2_month - d1_month - 1)) / 360
    return d_30360
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list `a = [False, True, True]`.
Is truth value False or True? It is indeed ambiguous.

Approach 1 - all of the elements must be True.

```py
>>> a = [False, True]
>>> all(a)
False
>>> a = [True, True, True, True]
>>> all(a)
True
>>> a = [False, False, False]
>>> all(a)
False
```

Approach 2 - at least one of the values must be True

```py
>>> a = [False, True]
>>> any(a)
True
>>> a = [True, True, True, True]
>>> any(a)
True
>>> a = [False, False, False]
>>> any(a)
False
```

Approach 3 - the list has only 1 item

```
>>> a = [False]
>>> bool(a)
False
>>> a = [True]
>>> bool(a)
True
```

Depending on what you want, use `any(a)` if you want at least one to be True, or `all(a)` if you want all of them.

Comment: Though not specifically stated, OP is probably using `numpy` arrays, which do have `all` and `any` methods such that allow to do `a.all()`

Comment: @Eric Jin So in this case, should I modify it like this: "if d2_month == d1_month:  all(d2_month)" Then I can execute the next equations right?

Comment: Your comparison `d2_month == d1_month` is fine, it is checking if the two lists are exactly the same. Can you add the full traceback so I know which line it is?

Comment: "d2_month == d1_month" is in line 40, bu the error is line 44 which starts from "+ 30 * (d2_month - d1_month - 1)) / 360"